# Convert JSON string to PHP Array

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON string, which was an Objective C array then encoded to JSON:

```
 $jsonString=[\"a@gmail.com\",\"b@gmail.com\",\"c@gmail.com\"]
```

I want to convert this to a regular PHP array. I've tried many things but none of them seem to work:

```
$arrayOfEmails=json_decode($jsonString); //doesn't work
$arrayOfEmails=(array)json_decode($jsonString); //doesn't work
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I'm still not getting it to work.

```
$decodeEmails=$_POST["arrayOfEmails"];
sendResponse(200, $decodeEmails);
//the above returns exactly whats after this colon:[\"a@gmail.com\",\"b@gmail.com\",\"c@gmail.com\]
```

I need to do this:  `$arrayOfEmails=json_decode($decodeEmails);`
But I think I need quotes around $decodedEmails for this to work. How can I add quotes around $decodeEmails string?

Comment: it seems like you have to escape the quotes inside the string for it to be valid: `"[\"m@gmail.com\",\"b@gmail.com\",\"c@gmail.com\"]"`

Comment: This is the Objective C version of the string..it gets sent to PHP via POST

Comment: You need to define "doesn't work." `json_decode()` is the proper method for this purpose, so what _are_ you getting when you use it?

Comment: I edited it now, that's the actual PHP string. Do I have to do anything to it first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should quote your string, it works fine, [see here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/U2zziN).

```
$jsonString = '["m@gmail.com","b@gmail.com","c@gmail.com"]';
$arrayOfEmails=json_decode($jsonString);
```

Or

```
$jsonString = "[\"a@gmail.com\",\"b@gmail.com\",\"c@gmail.com\"]";
$arrayOfEmails=json_decode($jsonString);
```

Comment: @mohabitar If you are already escape the `"`, then you can use `"`.

Comment: var_dump gives this (The actual array has more than 3, I took the extras off from here just so I can show it): `string(457) "[\"a@gmail.com\",\"b@gmail.com\",\"c@gmail.com\"]"`

Comment: @mohabitar It's already a string, you can just use json_decode after it .

Comment: But that's what I'm doing isn't it? `$decodeEmails=$_POST["arrayOfEmails"];
$arrayOfEmails=json_decode($decodeEmails);`

Answer (score 10):

Try this:
 *`json_decode($json_string, true);`*

Comment: This is correct, the other answers don't seem to know about the **second** argument for `json_decode()` and are only type-casting the first level elements.

Comment: But this returns an associative array, no? I just want a regular

Comment: @mohabitar, PHP only has one type of array. I think you mean that the array keys are not numeric then? Your input is what needs to be checked or corrected to get the output you desire.

Comment: There is no need for the second param in thie case given in the question. The second param is for converting JSON serialized objects to assoc arrays. The OP has a JSON serialized indexed array.

Comment: When I passed second parameter assoc= true to json_decode() its worked but I have to called it 2 times to achive my output

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = unserialize($data)
```

now u can get the $data as array

For example
$data have the value like this

> $data =
>   "a:2:{s:18:"_1337666504149_149";a:2:{s:8:"fbregexp";s:1:"1";s:5:"value";s:4:"2222";}s:18:"_1337666505594_594";a:2:{s:8:"fbregexp";s:1:"3";s:5:"value";s:5:"45555";}}";

```
$data = unserialize($data)
```

now i get value like this

```
Array ( [fbregexp] => 1 [value] => 2222 ) [_1337666505594_594] => Array ( [fbregexp] => 3 [value] => 45555 ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $str=<<<H
    {"a":"AAA","b":"333"}
    H;

     $object = json_decode($str); 
     $array  = json_decode($str , 1 );

    // $arr = get_object_vars( json_decode($str) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If `json_decode` isn't working, you could try something like this:

```
$arr = explode( '\\",\\"', substr( $json, 3, strlen( $json ) - 3 ) );
```

Comment: Worked for me as I was passing JSON string in URL

Answer (score 1):

You could use json_decode() then print_r() to create a PHP formatted array

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('json/yourscript.json'); // Get the JSON data
$phpObj = json_decode($json,true);  // Convert to PHP Object
print_r($phpObj);  // Convert to PHP Array
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine.

```
$jsonString = '["m@gmail.com","b@gmail.com","c@gmail.com"]';
$arrayOfEmails=json_decode($jsonString);
$arrayOfEmails=(array)json_decode($jsonString);
print_r($arrayOfEmails);
```

Comment: you don't have to escape the quotes in this case.

Comment: Instead of type-casting, you should be using the second argument to convert to an array: `json_decode($value, $array = TRUE)`.

Comment: Yes. I just tried to fix his error. Here is my result. Array ( [0] => m@gmail.com [1] => b@gmail.com [2] => c@gmail.com )

Comment: There is no need to typecast, _or_ to pass the second param as `true`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lack of quotes around your JSON in the question is a transposition error during posting, then the code you're using is fine: http://codepad.org/RWEYM42x

You do need to ensure your string is UTF8 encoded. You can use the built in encoder if it isn't ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php ).

For any further help, you need to actually tell us what you *are* getting with your code.

Answer (score -2):

```
$arr = explode( '\\",\\"', substr( $json, 3, strlen( $json ) - 3 ) )
```

This solution is good but for getting full valid array I'm  using `strlen( $json ) - 6`, so it should be:

```
$arr = explode( '\\",\\"', substr( $json, 3, strlen( $json ) - 6 ) );

var_dump($arr);
```