# Convert JSON string to PHP Variable

Tags: php, json, decode, encode

I have a JSON array with Yahoo Weather API data:

```
"query":{
  "count":1,
  "created":"2015-09-08T15:33:25Z",
  "lang":"en-US",
  "results":{
    "channel":{
      "item":{
        "condition":{
          "code":"30",
          "date":"Tue, 08 Sep 2015 11:13 am EDT",
          "temp":"81",
          "text":"Partly Cloudy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I just need to get `temp` and `text` and save them as variables... how do I do this?

I've tried encode, decode, subtr, and a few other methods, but can't seem to get the syntax right.
I've tried instructions from [Convert JSON string to PHP Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170639/convert-json-string-to-php-array)

Here's the code on my site:

```
  $BASE_URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
  $yql_query = 'select item.condition from weather.forecast  where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="'.$city.', '.$state.'")';
  $yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query) . "&format=json";
  // Make call with cURL
  $session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  $json = curl_exec($session);
  // Convert JSON to PHP object
  $phpObj =  json_decode($json);

    echo '<br><br><br><br>';

    echo $json;
```

Comment: I tried the suggestions in that link (echo $json->temp;) but it didn't echo anything

Comment: what do you get when you console.log($json) ?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $json is not defined(…)
I'm not using javascript at all for this, only php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First the result of a `json_decode()` should be an object or an array so to view it dont use `echo` try using `print_r()` or `var_dump()`

```
$phpObj =  json_decode($json);
print_r($phpObj);
```

To get the 2 values you are interested in as all the data structures in your data are objects use :-

```
echo $phpObj->query->result->channel->item->temp;
echo $phpObj->query->result->channel->item->text;
```

If you are not sure that the `json_decode()` is working, possibly the json string is badly formed then test the result of the `json_decode()` for any errors like so :-

```
$phpObj =  json_decode($json);
if ( json_last_error() !== 0 ) {
    echo json_last_error_msg();
} else {
    print_r($phpObj);
}
```

Comment: I tried what you put, but nothing was echoed. no errors given when I ran the second section, only echoed the string: 
stdClass Object ( [query] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 1 [created] => 2015-09-08T16:05:36Z [lang] => en-US [results] => stdClass Object ( [channel] => stdClass Object ( [item] => stdClass Object ( [condition] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 9 [date] => Tue, 08 Sep 2015 11:34 am EDT [temp] => 82 [text] => Light Drizzle ) ) ) ) ) )

Comment: JK I got it! I just had to add condition too! So glad I know the syntax now! Thanks so much!